# Transitioning between clear and translucent UINavigationBar states in iOS 10

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar, core-animation, ios10

As of iOS 10, the Contacts app has a very interesting visual effect with its implemetation of `UINavigationBar`.

From the root view controller, the bar appears normal, but upon tapping on a contact, the animation that plays will have JUST the background of the navigation bar fading out to completely clear, with the translucency effect also being scaled back to nothing at the same time.

Once the transition is complete, the back button and other controls of the navigation bar are still there; meaning it wasn't actually hidden.

When the contact view controller is popped, the animation is played back in reverse, and can even be controlled via the 'swipe-back' feature of `UINavigationController`:

[image: Example of the effect]

Does anyone know how to implement this feature? I suppose it's possible to get this effect by subclassing `UINavigationBar` and manually controlling the state of the background view, but I'm REALLY hoping to avoid that as I've discovered making third party navigation bars play nice with the status bar isn't easy. I'm wondering if there's a way to get it for free from the system.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know it works.

Comment: code updated....

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve navigationBar view transition from `clear` to `translucent` using `UIGestureRecognizer` and `UIVisualEffect`.

In **Main VC**:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
}
```

In **Detail VC**:

Implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your **Class** and use below code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let navigationBarBlurView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.size.width, height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!))
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light) // Set any style you want(.light or .dark) to achieve different effect.
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = navigationBarBlurView.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    navigationBarBlurView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    view.addSubview(navigationBarBlurView)
    return true
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! That looks like you got it working! Hmm, I just tried your code, but it fails on `statusBarView.addSubview(blurEffectView)`. What is `statusBarView` in this instance?